# Dealing with futures of Boolean

Tags: scala

```
def f1 = Future(true)
def f2 = Future(false)

case class Test(flag :Boolean= false , id :String)
```

f1 and f2 are methods which deals returns 
     `Future[Boolean]` .It is easy to do f1&&f2 if `boolean` 
    but how can we do that with futures 
    `new Test(id="123").copy(flag = f1 && f2)` doesnot work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@LeoC gives a pretty general answer, but there's [a specific method](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/concurrent/Future.html#zipWith[U,R](that:scala.concurrent.Future[U])(f:(T,U)=%3ER)(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[R]) for combining results of two futures with a function:

```
f1.zipWith(f2) { _ && _ }
```

> if i have to evaluate f2 after f1 is true f2 should not be evaluated if f1 is false

Then I'm afraid you need something like

```
f1.flatMap { x => if (x) f2 else Future.successful(false) }
```

At least I don't see a better option at the moment.

But note that isn't necessarily good: in the first solution `f1` and `f2` can be evaluated concurrently, so this will usually be faster than evaluating `f1` first before you can start `f2`.

You could also modify it so both are started together and if one is `false`, then the combined future immediately finishes with `false`, but that's even more complicated code.

Comment: How will i assign the value to result as it is a future

Comment: Thks but if i have to evaluate f2 after f1 is true f2 should not be evaluated if f1 is false

Comment: First: yes, of course combining futures gives a future and you handle it the same way you'd handle other futures (e.g. `f1.zipWith(f2) { _ && _ }.map( z => new Test(id = "123").copy(flag = z) )` as in LeoC's answer or `f1.zipWith(f2) { (x1, x2) => new Test(id="123").copy(flag = x1 && x2) }`) to simplify. Second: see the edit.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `for-comprehension` to yield a Future from values of f1 and f2, then `map/recover` to return a Future of the derived case class:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

def f1 = Future{ true }
def f2 = Future{ false }

case class Test(flag: Boolean = false, id: String)

val f = for {
  x <- f1
  y <- f2
} yield x && y

f.map( z => Test(id = "123").copy(flag = z) ).recover{ case e => "Failure: " + e }
// res1: Future[java.io.Serializable] = Future(Success(Test(false,123)))
```

To capture success/failure value in a container type, make `map/recover` return a Future of `Either[Throwable, Test]`:

```
f.map( z => Right(Test(id = "123").copy(flag = z)) ).recover{ case e => Left(e) }
// res2: Future[Product with Serializable with Either[Throwable,Test]] =
//   Future(Success(Right(Test(false,123))))
```

Or, use `onComplete` to simply output the success/failure value:

```
f.onComplete{
  case Success(z) => println("Success: " + Test(id = "123").copy(flag = z))
  case Failure(e) => println("Failure: " + e)
}
// Success: Test(false,123)
```

Alternatively, use `flatMap/map` instead of the `for-comprehension`:

```
f1.flatMap(x => f2.map(y => x && y)).
  map( z => Test(id = "123").copy(flag = z) ).recover{ case e => "Failure: " + e }
```

Comment: Thks but if i have to evaluate f2 after f1 is true f2 should not be evaluated if f1 is false

Comment: @coder25, I think Alexey's expanded answer using `flatMap` with the `if/else` function has addressed your specific requirement of evaluating `f1` first and `f2` conditionally.  But unless you're certain `f1` requires significantly less time to evaluate than `f2` does and has a good chance of returning `false`, there is probably not a lot of benefit (since `f2` would now be evaluated after `f1` returns).